# How to create an android app that runs R script?

Tags: android, html, r, server

I am having a R code that produces results given a input. I would like to create a server based app, that is the code should run on my server, but the input should be given in by an app the output of the code also should be shown on the app. Any Ideas on what I should be looking on?

Comment: You might consider [`OpenCPU`](https://www.opencpu.org/), a RESTful API for calls to individual R functions. Arbitrary packages can be installed, so if you need something non-standard (e.g., chained functions), you can easily write your own package and install it for the server to reference.

Comment: You could set up Shiny Server and create a wrapper around it.
This is by far not the optimal solution, but it is, arguably, the easiest.